# Adjust fontsize in jquery poshytip

Tags: jquery, popup, mouseover, font-size

I have poshytips which come up on mouseover which are designed as follows:

```
// Function to make poshytip table
    function maketip1(t) {
        // console.log(d)
        var d= t.properties.ID
        var num = 1
        var region_name = allData.metadata.region_names[d]
        var metric_name = allData.data[d][current_settings.surveys[num]][current_settings.variables[num]].name
        var value = String(allData.data[d][current_settings.surveys[num]][current_settings.variables[num]].value*100).substring(0,5)
        var table = '<table><tr><td><u><b>' + region_name + '</b></u></td><tr><td><u>' + metric_name + ': </u></td><td>' + value + '</td></tr></table>'
        return table;
    }

// Make poshytips pop up for reg-path1 class
    $('.reg-path1').poshytip({
        content: function() {
            return maketip1(this.__data__); 
        },
        className: 'tip-ihme',
        slide:      false,
        followCursor:   true,
        alignTo:    'cursor',
        alignX:     'center'
    });
```

I have tried passing the following arguments into the .poshytip call, without any change:

```
fontSize = 25
fontSize = '25'
fontSize = '25px'
```

I have also tried making a css class which corresponds to the className argument in the .poshytip call:

```
.tip-ihme {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

How can I adjust the fontsize in the poshytips that pop up?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table that's being returned, include the following tag before your html code:

```
<font size=3>
```

In this case:

```
var table = '<font size=3><table><tr><td><u><b>' + region_name + '</b></u></td><tr><td><u>' + metric_name + ': </u></td><td>' + value + '</td></tr></table>'
```